# How to send email whenever Infrastructure (ARM templates) provisioning completed in azure through the VSTS release?

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

I am working on ARM templates, currently I developed ARM templates for Web App and Azure SQL database. And deployed those are in Azure through the VSTS release definition.

VSTS release Definition:
[image]

I want to send mail to project manager, whenever Infrastructure provisioning completed in azure. For that I used **Send Grid Email** task but I have few questions like:

1. How to give the output of Web App and Azure SQL Server ARM templates to Email Body section in **Send Grid Email** task?
2. Is it recommended to use the Send Grid Email task?
3. How to send email with PowerShell task execution summary like the below image.
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t get the output of Web App and ARM template deployment tasks, you can get the related information by calling Azure PowerShell or other way, for example: [Get-AzureRmResourceGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermresourcegroup?view=azurermps-5.6.0).

Regarding send email during build/release, you can use Send Grid Email or other task, just per to your requirement or which you prefer.

Update:

Simple sample to get the output:

```
$r=New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -ResourceGroupName xxx -TemplateFile t.json

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pState;]$($r.ProvisioningState)"
```

Comment: Thanks Starian, But how to pass the PowerShell output to Email body Section in Send Grid Email task.

Comment: @pradeep You can store the result in a variable through [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md), e.g. `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"`, then use that variable in other tasks directly.

Comment: I know the above cmdlets. But I want to save the PowerShell task execution output in one variable.

Comment: `$r=Invoke-RestMethod xxxx Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=result;]$r"`

Comment: Starian, can you please update your answer for "how to pass the PowerShell task output to other task". Currently I used the PowerShell task for deploying the ARM templates. So, I want to send the email with ARM template status whether it is "succeeded or failed" using Send Grid Email task.

Comment: @pradeep What's the detail code to deploy ARM template? I update the  answer with simple code.

Comment: Starian, I have to write these two lines of code to set the multiple parameters Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=parameters;]$($r.Parameters)" and outputs Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ouputs;]$($r.Outputs)" but it will store the object value of parameters and outputs. can you please tell me how to set the task variable for storing the multiple values at a time

Comment: @pradeep No you can't, you can combine them together.

Comment: Starian, Actually I didn't understand of your comment. can you please elaborate your comment.

Comment: I mean combine the string together and store in a variable.